# how to handle ajax parsererror nicely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a google ad project which requires me to get multiple "setTargeting('', '');" from an object array on json file (via url) --> {"country": "Netherlands", "city": "Amsterdam" }. So far everything works; however, suppose the network fails, or requested JSON parse failed, etc - I'd like to pass an empty array to make sure that the slot will still show ads with no targeting.

What would be a good practise for it?

```html
Advertisements.cachedCategoriesByUrl = {};

Advertisements.getCategories = function(categoriesUrl) {

    var cachedCategories = Advertisements.cachedCategoriesByUrl[categoriesUrl];

    if(cachedCategories){

        return cachedCategories;

    } else {

        var getCategories = $.ajax({
            url: categoriesUrl,
            data: { format: 'json' },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, thrownError) {
                => I'd like to pass an empty array so the slot will show 
                ads with no targetting set. 
                However this doesn't seem to be working.

                Do I need to do callback?
            }
        });

        Advertisements.cachedCategoriesByUrl[categoriesUrl] = getCategories;
        return getCategories;
    }
}
```

Note:
return getCategories runs before the ajax call finishes. How do I make sure that return getCategories gets my error update(I want to pass an empty array if JSON request fails or invalid). Sorry I am in the learning process.

Comment: Are you doing something else with the `jqXHR` object? Why are you storing it (`getCategories`)?

Comment: I need getCategories to get the categories to pass it inside the slot function so that the "setTargeting" can be as many as categories defined inside the json file. I updated `jqXHR.responseText = '{}';` on error, but it seems like google doesn't get the updated array. That's why I thought that I need to do callback or something.. (sorry I am new to this)

Comment: Are you aware that your last `return getCategories;` is running before your ajax request completes?

Comment: In that case, shall I be doing callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: ad.categoriesUrl
}).then(function(data){
    Advertisements.advertisementSlot(ad, data);
}, function(data){
    data = {};
    Advertisements.advertisementSlot(ad, data);
});
```

Comment: I think this always shows the no region ad, even if the region callback works.